# DynamoDb error that gives KeyConditionExpression is undefined

Tags: dynamodb-queries

Before I only used requestVersion variable and this query worked. Now I added start and end dates like this.

```
KeyConditionExpression: 'request_version = :request_version AND completed_date_time > :start_date AND completed_date_time < :end_date',
```

I get this error

```
"Invalid KeyConditionExpression: An expression attribute value used in expression is not defined; attribute value: :end_date"
```

My expressions variables Look like this.

```
ExpressionAttributeValues = {
  ':start_date': filters.startDate,
  ':endDate': filters.endDate,
  ':request_version': filters.requestVersion
}
```

I know the variables are not null. All 3 are being passed over correctly. So I'm guessing I'm missing something here in the set up. some examples have the expression attribute values inside an object. Not sure why and if I should try that.

I'll take any suggestions on what I am missing here. Thanks.